# Difference between configuring connection via PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and HttpClientBuilder

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have two restTemplate configurations. One is configuring connection with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and other one is directly configured via HttpClientBuilder. Both are having connection related configuration using HttpClient.

Below is one with `HttpClientBuilder`

```
        final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        httpClientBuilder.setMaxConnTotal(maxConnPerRoute);
        httpClientBuilder.setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnPerRoute);
        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionReuseStrategy(new NoConnectionReuseStrategy());

        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
            = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder.build());

        final BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory =
            new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
       final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory);
```

Here we are directly setting httpClient like

```
httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder.build());
```

Below is  `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`

```
   private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(final ConnectionPooling connectionPooling) {
        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
       
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(connectionPooling.getMaxConnections());

        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(connectionPooling.getMaxConnections());

        final HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .build();

        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory connectionFactory =
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpclient);
        connectionFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionPooling.getConnectionTimeout());
        connectionFactory.setReadTimeout(connectionPooling.getReadTimeout());
        connectionFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionPooling.getConnectionRequestTimeoutMillis());

        final IdleConnectionEvictor idleConnectionTimeoutThread =
            new IdleConnectionEvictor(connectionManager,
                connectionPooling.getIdleConnectionCheckMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                connectionPooling.getIdleConnectionTimeoutMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        idleConnectionTimeoutThread.start();

        return new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(connectionFactory);
    }
```

Here we are setting like

```
        final HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .build();
```

What is the difference between these two configuration? Is it both will react differently?

Answer (score 0):

They will behave differently. Since your first HttpClientBuilder doesn't set a connection manager, it is thread-unsafe. It is useful to have a connection manager like your second example for many reasons. The Apache documentation boils down the benefits of a connection manager well [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html):

> The purpose of an HTTP connection manager is to serve as a factory for new HTTP connections, to manage life cycle of persistent connections and to synchronize access to persistent connections making sure that only one thread can have access to a connection at a time.